# sticky header - add padding with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to remove the logo from my fixed header after scrolling but I also want to add a padding to my menu to center it in the header.  Can someone please help me revise this code to add padding to lets say .main-menu.  THANKS!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){        
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    $("#logo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 128);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask what this is for, but I think maybe a straight answer might be best.  Here's a literal answer to your question:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){        
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    $("#logo").toggle($(this).scrollTop() < 128);
    $(".main_menu").css('padding', 5);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Worked great except for the fact that the menu padding is not reset when < 128.  So it is essentially permanently changing the padding.  With the logo toggle the effect reverses when less than 128.  Any advice to make the padding reset when scrolling up?